# 'Bad credentials' with Symfony2 authentication custom provider

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, provider

I have a project with simple authentication by mysql database with username and password. I have simple form for authentication with 3 fields: pass, user and yubico key. I want to have two variants of authentication: by login+pass and by only [yubico key](http://www.yubico.com/). Now I created custom Authentication Provider by tutorial in [this topic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).

As a result, it does not work. I get this error log:

> exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException'
>   with message 'Bad credentials' in
>   E:\Dropbox\hmciAdmin\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php:70
>   Stack trace: #0 E:\Dropbox\hmciAdmin\app\cache\dev\classes.php(183):
>   session_start() #1
>   E:\Dropbox\hmciAdmin\app\cache\dev\classes.php(277):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()

My code here:

- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/Authentication/Firewall/YubicoListener.php
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/Authentication/Provider/YubicoProvider.php
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/Authentication/Token/YubicoToken.php
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/Authentication/Token/config/services.yml
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/Authentication/Token/config/config/security.yml

**UPDATE:**

- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/YubicoFactory.php - here Factory

**UPDATE 2:**

I solve this problem. The problem was that I used the same html form for both types of authorizations, but it was necessary to send yubico key to url of the page that is being protected. Now all work. Thanks all for help.

Comment: Strange one ... doesnt seem to be using your authentication provider - I will have another look at the configs ...

Comment: I also think that some problem in configs, but I can not figure out what is wrong. The code of the provider basically works, as with logs, I found that the user correctly identifies by custom provider. although I think I did everything right by guides

Comment: Try removing the `form_login` section of your security config - because that too is an authentication provider - it might use that before using yours.

Comment: Removed. And I get:
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
when try to authenticate.

Comment: Im not sure that is the problem - have seen others use the form_login and a custom authentication provider !!! sorry still looking !